# Creating an accrual template using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an automated accrual template. It has the following requirements:

- The data must first be sorted by account and then by business unit. An offsetting line must be inserted for each business unit for two groups: lines with account "101" and lines with all other account numbers.
- The offsetting line should reflect the proper business unit above.
- The account number for the offsetting line should be "750" if it is for the "101" group and it should be "780" if it is for the all other accounts group.
- The transaction type should always be "25" for the offsetting line.
- The amount on the offsetting line should be a negative subtotal of the above group meaning that it should "zero out" the above lines.

My code currently sorts the data by account and then by business unit. 
It correctly inserts the business unit. It also correctly inserts "25" for transaction type on the offsetting lines. What it fails to do is to say "if the lines above are 101 then 750 or if lines above do not equal 101 then 780. It also fails to create a negative subtotal for the above group.

Please look at the end result tab if you wish to see the final result.

I've posted the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct5mi5dxv1zyoip/Macro%20Test.xlsm?dl=0).

```
Sub accrualMacro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'CLEAR ALL FILTERS
With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'FILTER AND SORT
Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("B10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACCRUAL TEMPLATE").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

With Range("A10", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(1), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    .Offset(2, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(,     1).ClearContents
    .Offset(, -1).EntireColumn.Delete
    .EntireColumn.RemoveSubtotal
End With

End With

'INSERT BLANK ROWS AT
Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "B"
    StartRow = 10
    BlankRows = 1

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet
For R = lastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If .Cells(R, Col) = "101" And .Cells(R + 1, Col) <> "101" Then
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next R
End With

'new method below
With ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A" & lastRow)
  Set myrange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
 myrange.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
 .Value = .Value
End If
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("C10:C" & lastRow)
  Set myrange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
 myrange.FormulaR1C1 = "25"
End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the VBA code you have written thus far and include your attempts to write the requested tasks. Also, please point out where in the code the program halts / runs into errors / or does not behave as expected. Thank you.

Comment: In short, I am stuck at developing the VBA that inserts a negative subtotal amount at each correcting line entry. I can get it to subtotal the entire column but I only need it to subtotal the group above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understood correctly. But it would seem to me that you are looking for the following few lines of code in order to complete your macro:

```
Dim lngStartRow As Long
Dim lngEndRow As Long

lngStartRow = 11

For lngEndRow = 11 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(lngEndRow, 4).Formula) = vbNullString Then
        Sheet1.Cells(lngEndRow, 4).Formula = "=-SUM(D" & lngStartRow & ":D" & lngEndRow - 1 & ")"
        lngStartRow = lngEndRow + 1
    End If
Next lngEndRow
```

Basically, the `For ... Next` loop iterates through the rows and checks for the empty ones (starting with the first row being 11). If there is a blank row (in column D) then all above cells will be summarized with a `SUM` formula. Furthermore, the "new starting point" for the next `SUM` is being set to the next available line. The process is being repeated until all rows in column D have been summarized (except for the last chunk). If you also wish to include the last block then you will have to expand upon the loop with a `+1`.

Comment: Ralph, you understood correctly. I do need the last block summarized. What exactly did you mean by expand upon the loop with a +1?

Comment: `For lngEndRow = 11 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Ralph, this works. Additionally, I need some code that says "for each summary block where the account = 101 then account in offset line equals 750 Else offset line equals 780. I created this bit of code below but it inserted 750 into the account column of each offset line.
 
`With ActiveSheet.Range("B10:B" & lastRow)Set myrange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
    If myrange.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Value = "101" Then
     myrange.FormulaR1C1 = "750"
     Else
     myrange.FormulaR1C1 = "780"
  End If
  End If
End With`

Comment: With the solution I provided you shouldn't have any problems adapting your code to do as you wish. Still if you are (once again ) running into an error / problem then you can post a new question It is never good to post questions wich (essentially) consist of 5 or more questions. Anyway, I consider this question solved.